# How to fetch data from json in Angular2 (TypeScript) without HTTP?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have task (auth): 
All data should be stored in LocalStorage.
Application should be written without back-end languages or services
You should create a json file with 10 test users and get it content while application forming.
Save user to LocalStorage.

I create a json file with data of users, but i don't understand how to fetch it in my service.

```
{
  "Users": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "name": "FirstUser",
      "email": "1stemail@gmail.com",
      "password": "test123"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "name": "2thUser",
      "email": "2themail@gmail.com",
      "password": "test123"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried some tricks like

`"import as data from '../shared/users.json'

"const users = data.Users"` (error on Users)

Do you have idea "how to" ?

Comment: Please check this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html where demo application is loading data from .json file

Comment: and this the live plunkr for that https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview

Comment: @Mohtisham of course i saw that ... but my task require solution without server, as far as i understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be `import * as data from '../shared/users.json` but your system.config might add `.ts` or `.js` extension at the end of it.

The way I prefer to do it is to export it as a variable inside a **ts** file

```
export var data = {
  "Users": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "name": "FirstUser",
      "email": "1stemail@gmail.com",
      "password": "test123"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "name": "2thUser",
      "email": "2themail@gmail.com",
      "password": "test123"
    }
  ]
}
```

then import that variable inside your component

```
import { data } from '../shared/users';
```

Full plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/CGtxYJkcjYt2cEzrbL00?p=info

Comment: Of course, ts file better and more comfortable, but it's my technical task with "json data" ... about "import * as data from ...." i did that ... and add to system.configjs extension ...

Comment: i forget, i'll test now. About this trick, i did all like there https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79#.unrmgvr1a

Comment: @МаксимТарсис but you are missing the `*` be careful about that

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c636321/v636321071/56991/Sie4ttIA_dE.jpg (error: Property "Users" does not exist on type 'typeof"*.json"' )

Comment: @МаксимТарсис without http I don't think that'll be possible tbh :/

Comment: @МаксимТарсис haha, no problem. Maybe someone will come up with an answer :-)